# Schedule [Virtualenv Dependent] Python Script with Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, python, windows-task-scheduler

I want to schedule a Python script to start at 3AM and break at 5PM every weekday. However the problem arises when I need to start virtualenv as all the packages are install in a virtual environment.

I can get the script to run at a specific time but I can't activate the virtual environment (I'd normally type "`env\scripts\activate`"). Here is what my action looks like:

[image]

How can I incorporate activating virtualenv and what should my action look like to break the script?

Answer (score 1):

My workon.bat script wouldn't set Env properties properly but this final command worked in Task Scheduler:

cmd /C c:/Users/name/Env/workon_name/Scripts/activate.bat & python run_script.py

Answer (score 1):

You create a Windows batch file e.g. MyProgram.bat with the following content:

```
cd C:\PathToYourPythonFile
call C:\PathToYourCondaInstallation\Scripts\activate.bat YourEnv
python YourPythonFile.py
```

Make sure you replace `YourEnv` with a conda environment that you set up before.

You can start the batch file from your Task Scheduler, no additional arguments needed.

**Add on:**

Alternatively, to avoid the pop-up window I let the Task Scheduler call a three-line MyProgram.vbs file instead which calls the above batch file like this:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\PathToYourBatchFile\MyProgram.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

It is a bit awkward to always have three files (what would you expect with Windows...) but I use the same names for the files, so it's OK. I'd be happy to hear a better solution.

Comment: This (@sdittmar) worked for me

Answer (score 0):

What if you create a batch file, e.g. `test.bat`, that first activates your virtual environment, then runs your python script? Something like:

```
env\scripts\activate
D:\Python\Aldabra\env\Scripts\python.exe "D:\Python_scpt\test.py"
```

Then have that script run from Windows Task Scheduler.

In your script, I would also suggest making the `env\scripts\activate` part not depend on where the script is run. i.e. make it an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

you can create it in the command line using `schtasks` and specifying the path to the python executable inside your virtual environment directory

```
schtasks /Create /SC HOURLY /TN VirtualEnvPythonTask /TR "PATH_TO_VIRTUAL_ENV_PYTHON_EXECUTABLE PATH_TO_PYTHON_SCRIPT"
```

alternatively, you can use the task scheduler GUI with `Action: start a program`
Set the `Program/script:` to the python executable in the virtual environment path, and add the python script in the `Add arguments (optional):` field

For example, I'm using conda, with an environment call MSSQL-ETL-ENV. The path to python would be

```
C:\Users\dbaker\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\MSSQL-ETL-ENV\python
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are directly calling the `python.exe` file in the virtual environment, you are indeed indirectly activating the `virtualenvironment`.

When you type `.\env\Scripts\activate`, you are just changing the path variable, such that the path to your `Lib` directory which contains the libraries installed in your virtualenvironment to occur first. As a result when python searches for those libraries it finds these libraries in the virtualenv first and uses them.

If you dont have any other constraints, then just using 
`C:\path_to_virtualenvip\python.exe C:\path_to_python_file.py`

should be enough to run the python file in your virtual-environment.