# Execute Python script in Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

I have a Python script which is running in Windows Task Scheduler. The script contains some print commands so that when it run from PyCharm, I can see the print in the console. However, I can't see those when executed from the Task Scheduler.

Following is my configuration of the scheduler.

[image: Image. Scheduler action configuration. A Daily task is set to Start a Program, Python. A script called A dot P Y, followed by two greater than symbols, then a file name given as test dot log, is shown. The script, symbols, and file name, are all listed as Arguments to the Python executable]

Any suggestions what to do?

Comment: Is your full location `C:\path\to\python.exe`? Are there spaces or special characters in the path? Is it under a User folder, something like `Program Files` or a custom folder? I take it `text.log` is blank or is there something else that happens? Please consider [edit]ing your question to include these details.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1142185/schedule-virtualenv-dependent-python-script-with-windows-task-scheduler